# How to see database connections as a regular developer?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-connection, sqlplus

How can a regular developer, without admin privileges on the database, see active db connections - particularly the ones "owned" by them? Not sure if that is the right db terminology. (Application written in Java with JDBC, Oracle, and SQL Plus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need admin privileges but you would need to have permission to query the `V$SESSION` table (`GV$SESSION` if you happen to be using RAC).  Your DBA can grant you the privilege to query just that table

```
GRANT SELECT ON sys.v_$session TO <<your user name>>
```

or the DBA can grant your user the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege or the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` role.

If you have one of those grants, you should be able to query `V$SESSION` to see all the sessions in the database.

```
SELECT sid, serial#, username, osuser, machine, terminal, program
  FROM v$session
 WHERE username = <<some user name>>
```

will show all the sessions in the database opened by a particular user.

Comment: Thanks so much, Justin. Great info!

Comment: @Iceberg - if it's a good answer, please Accept it (click on the little 'checkmark' to the left of the answer).  This is considered good manners on StackOverflow and its related sites.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I haven't asked a question before so didn't know about the check. Excellent answer for my situation. Thanks again.